# Split file based on \r into new rows

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have an csv file in my source folder, want to get the output as new line where we have "\r"

**Source File**
\name\age\gender\r\kiran\29\male\r\rekha\12\female\r\siva\39\male\r

**Expected output file**

\name\age\gender

\kiran\29\male

\rekha\12\female

\siva\39\male

Comment: Have you tried anything? Why did you tag pyspark and apache-spark-sql?

Comment: if you split by `\r` why are you preserving it in the result?

Comment: remove the \r is also fine.

Comment: kindly give the code

Comment: Hi D Malan, Which skill i have to take

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('filename.csv', 'r+') as file:
    data = file.readlines()[0].replace(('\\r\\','\n\\'))[:-1]

print(data)
```

[image]